# subview hiding the table view iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have an image view on which i have included a table view. Now i wanted to insert a subview on the image view through which i wanted to show an extended background image.

I have added a subview like so on viewDidLoad....

```
if([data count]>3)
{
    UIImageView *i=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
    [i setFrame:CGRectMake(1.25,350,321,210)];
    [[self view] addSubview:i];
    //[[self view] sendSubviewToBack:i];
    [i release], i=nil;
}
```

The problem is the table view is not showing up in the region where i added the sub view. I tried to send the subview to back but if i do so only the previous image view is showing up... Plz help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the image view

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myTableView];
```

Comment: Thanks... Solved the problem in ten mins after posting the question... Thanks for the reply anyway...